# How to set custom font with regular and bold font while setting html string to label in swift 4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, swift4

I am getting `HTML` formatted string from `API` response, so I need to set it to a label while maintaining Custom Font(as of my App) and also applying a style(bold, regular, etc.) to the label.

I have used an extension that enables to convert the `HTML` string to regular string with newlines etc. but, I was able to set font here, but only one font and it shows in regular font only, so the whole label is in one font, what I want is to set bold font to the bold `HTML` part and regular to regular `HTML` part/tag.

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString.string
    }
}

//set converted html to string here
let whyAttendAttributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attendData.whyAttendData?.desc?.htmlToAttributedString ?? NSAttributedString())

//set font here   
whyAttendAttributedText.addAttributes([NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: CommonSettings.shared.getFont(type: .regular, size: descriptionLabel.font.pointSize), NSMutableAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], range: NSMakeRange(0, whyAttendAttributedText.length))
```

I want to set bold and regular to the text, but as I have set only one font I was unable to get the result, is there any way to set the bold and regular font as in `HTML` string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help :

```
extension String {

func attributedString(withRegularFont regularFont: UIFont, andBoldFont boldFont: UIFont) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }
        do {
            attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                                             options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                                       .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                                             documentAttributes: nil)
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
            attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { value, range, _ in
                let currentFont: UIFont         = value as! UIFont
                var replacementFont: UIFont?    = nil

                if currentFont.fontName.contains("bold") || currentFont.fontName.contains("Bold") {
                    replacementFont             =   boldFont
                } else {
                    replacementFont             =   regularFont
                }

                let replacementAttribute        =   [NSAttributedString.Key.font:replacementFont!]
                attributedString.addAttributes(replacementAttribute, range: range)
            }
        } catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
       return attributedString
}
}
```

Comment: it worked!!! thank you so much there. It was giving some error, I have just edited it, do approve

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your string after parsing HTML string is: `"This is your HTML string"`

To create an `attributed string`,

```
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is your HTML string")
```

Adding `UIFont` attribute with value as `System-Regular`,

```
attrStr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .regular), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length))
```

Whenever adding an `attribute` to the `attributed string`, we need to provide the `range` of `string` in which we want to reflect the `attribute`.

Since we need the whole `string` to have `Regular` font, so the `range` is calculated as the whole `string` `length`.

Now, adding `UIFont` attribute with value as `System-Bold` to a part of the `string`, let's say we make **`HTML`** as bold,

```
attrStr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .bold), range: (attrStr.string as NSString).range(of: "HTML"))
```

We've calculated the `range` of HTML word within the whole string.

Similarly, you can add any of the `attributes` to the `string` giving the relevant `range` values.

**Output:** `This is your`**`HTML`**`string`

**Edit-1:**

To calculate the `range` of `<b> to </b>` you need to calculate it manually.

**Example:**

```
let str = "This <b>is your HTML</b> string"
let range1 = (str as NSString).range(of: "<b>")
let range2 = (str as NSString).range(of: "</b>")
let requiredRange = NSRange(location: range1.location, length: range2.location + range2.length - range1.location)
```

The above example will work for single instance of `<b>/</b>` in the `string`.

**Edit-2:**

When `string` includes multiple instances of `<b>/</b>`:

```
let htmlStr = "This is an <b>HTML</b> parsed <b>string</b>"
let arr = htmlStr.components(separatedBy: "</b>")
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
for str in arr {
    if !str.isEmpty {
        let range1 = (str as NSString).range(of: "<b>")
        let requiredRange = NSRange(location: range1.location, length: str.count - range1.location)

        let formattedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
        formattedStr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .bold), range: requiredRange)
        attrStr.append(formattedStr)
        attrStr.append(NSAttributedString.init(string: "</b>", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .bold)]))
    }
}
self.label.attributedText = attrStr
```

**Output:** `This is an`**`<b>HTML</b>`**`parsed`**`<b>string</b>`**

Comment: is there any way to calculate range of <b> to </b> in string? and apply the above logic

Comment: Does the string contain a single instance of <b> and </b>?

Comment: no, it may contain many <b> tags, thank you so much for the update

Comment: Updated the code for multiple instance. Give it a try and see if it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Applying Bold and other different styles to the text can be done using below method.

```
extension String {

    func attributedString(with style: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil,
                          and highlightedText: String,
                          with highlightedTextStyle: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: style)
        let highlightedTextRange: NSRange = (self as NSString).range(of: highlightedText as String)
        formattedString.setAttributes(highlightedTextStyle, range: highlightedTextRange)
        return formattedString
    }
}
```

Input: "This is a test message"

Expectd Output: "This is a **test** message"

This can be achieved as follows.

```
let sampleInput = "This is a test message"
let boldtext = "test"

let output = sampleInput.attributedString(with: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .regular)],
                             and: boldtext, with: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .bold))
```

Different styles can be applied using different attribute keys. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not help, I don't know what is bold text, I only have one string which contains bold tags and regular text